# Trying to insert dashes between 2 odd numbers.Error: Illegal return statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

```
function insertDash(str) {

    var arr = str.split("");

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0 && arr[i + 1] % 2 != 0) {

            var x = arr.splice(i + 1, 0, '-');

        }

    }

    return arr;

}

console.log(insertDash("99999"));
```

Comment: you run into an endless loop at the end of the array

Comment: You're trying to splice past the end of the string.  Your loop runs for all indexes (0-4, in this case) and then tries to insert at (i=4) + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate from the end of the array, because you probably insert a dash and the array gets a new length.

If you start at the end, you change not the length of the items which are eligible to test and for inserting a dash.

```js
function insertDash(string) {
    var array = string.split(""),
        i = array.length;

    while (i--) {
        if (array[i] % 2 && array[i + 1] % 2) {
            array.splice(i + 1, 0, '-');
        }
    }
    return array.join('');
}

console.log(insertDash("99999"));
console.log(insertDash("1122334455"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression with a [lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead):

```js
function insertDash(string) {
    return string.replace(/([13579](?=[13579]))/g, "$1-");
}

console.log(insertDash("99999"));
console.log(insertDash("1122334455"));
```

The other option is to use Array#reduce to create the string:

```js
function insertDash(string) {
    return string.split('').reduce(function(s, c, i, arr) {
      return s + c + (c % 2 && arr[i + 1] % 2 ? '-' : '');
    }, '');
}

console.log(insertDash("99999"));
console.log(insertDash("1122334455"));
```